# Run meta-analysis over multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, data-analysis, metafor

I'm a beginner with R. I would need your help to automate these analyses and to get a summary output with the results.

I have 4 different data frames like this (see below), with the same headers and the same values in the Threshold column:

```
   Set   Threshold  R2           P          Coefficient  Standard.Error  Num_SNP
Base  0.0001     0.000233304  0.66047    0.0332613    0.0757204       47
Base  0.001      0.000387268  0.571772   -0.0438782   0.0775996       475
Base  0.05       0.00302399   0.114364   0.129474     0.082004        14164
Base  0.1        0.00252797   0.14897    0.117391     0.0813418       24616
Base  0.2        0.00481908   0.0465384  0.163571     0.0821767       41524
Base  0.3        0.00514761   0.0398082  0.170058     0.0827237       55307
Base  0.4        0.00699506   0.0166685  0.200571     0.083783        66943
Base  0.5        0.00634181   0.0226301  0.192314     0.0843623       76785
```

For each matching value in the Threshold columns, I would like to use the package metafor in R to meta-analyse the corresponding effect sizes (in the Coefficient column) and standard errors over the 4 data frames.

Using the metafor package:

```
rma.uni(yi=c(Coefficient_1,Coefficient_2,Coefficient_3,Coefficient_4),sei=c(Standard.Error_1,Standard.Error_2,Standard.Error_3,Standard.Error_4), measure="GEN", method='FE',intercept=T,weights=c(sample_size1,sample_size2,sample_size3,sample_size4))
```

How could I automate the analyses and get a summary data frame with the results for each Threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there this should get you started. Essentially you can loop over all thresholds
extract the rows matching each threshold from all 4 dataframes into a new dataframe and run your meta-analysis

```
library(metafor)
# Make some fake data resembling your own
df1 = data.frame(Set=rep("Base",8), Threshold=c(0.0001,0.001,0.05,seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)),
                 R2=runif(8,0.001,0.005),P=runif(8,0.001,1),Coefficient=runif(8,-0.1,0.2),
                 Standard.Error=runif(8,0.07,0.08),Num_SNP=sample(1:1000,8))
df2 = data.frame(Set=rep("Base",8), Threshold=c(0.0001,0.001,0.05,seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)),
                 R2=runif(8,0.001,0.005),P=runif(8,0.001,1),Coefficient=runif(8,-0.1,0.2),
                 Standard.Error=runif(8,0.07,0.08),Num_SNP=sample(1:1000,8))
df3 = data.frame(Set=rep("Base",8), Threshold=c(0.0001,0.001,0.05,seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)),
                 R2=runif(8,0.001,0.005),P=runif(8,0.001,1),Coefficient=runif(8,-0.1,0.2),
                 Standard.Error=runif(8,0.07,0.08),Num_SNP=sample(1:1000,8))
df4 = data.frame(Set=rep("Base",8), Threshold=c(0.0001,0.001,0.05,seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)),
                 R2=runif(8,0.001,0.005),P=runif(8,0.001,1),Coefficient=runif(8,-0.1,0.2),
                 Standard.Error=runif(8,0.07,0.08),Num_SNP=sample(1:1000,8))

Thresholds = unique(df1$Threshold)

Results <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(Thresholds)){
  idf = rbind(df1[df1$Threshold==Thresholds[i],],
              df2[df2$Threshold==Thresholds[i],],
              df3[df3$Threshold==Thresholds[i],],
              df4[df4$Threshold==Thresholds[i],])
  i.meta <- rma.uni(yi=idf$Coefficient,sei=idf$Standard.Error, measure="GEN", method='FE',intercept=T,
                    weights=idf$Num_SNP)
  Results <- rbind(Results, c(Threshold=Thresholds[i],beta=i.meta$beta,se=i.meta$se,
                              zval=i.meta$zval,pval=i.meta$pval,ci.lb=i.meta$ci.lb,
                              ci.ub=i.meta$ci.ub,QEp=i.meta$QEp))
}
Results <- data.frame(Results)
Results
```

should give you :

```
  Threshold         beta         se       zval       pval        ci.lb     ci.ub        QEp
1     1e-04 -0.012079013 0.04715546 -0.2561530 0.79783270 -0.104502022 0.0803440 0.08700919
2     1e-03  0.068932388 0.04006086  1.7206917 0.08530678 -0.009585452 0.1474502 0.22294419
3     5e-02  0.050069503 0.04094881  1.2227340 0.22143020 -0.030188694 0.1303277 0.07342661
4     1e-01  0.102598016 0.04188183  2.4497022 0.01429744  0.020511132 0.1846849 0.07380669
5     2e-01  0.069482160 0.04722693  1.4712401 0.14122619 -0.023080930 0.1620452 0.95494364
6     3e-01  0.009793206 0.05098346  0.1920859 0.84767489 -0.090132542 0.1097190 0.12191340
7     4e-01  0.030432884 0.03967771  0.7670021 0.44308028 -0.047333994 0.1081998 0.86270334
8     5e-01  0.073511575 0.03997485  1.8389458 0.06592316 -0.004837683 0.1518608 0.12333557
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. I imagine that in this part of the script { idf = rbind(df1[df2$Threshold==Thresholds[i],] } there should be df1 in place of df2, right? However, how could I get an output data frame for all the Thresholds, showing at each row the Threshold value from the input data.frames, and the corresponding results from the meta-analysis (ie. at each row: Threshold, beta, se, zval, pval, ci.lb, ci.ub, QEp)? Many thanks again!

Comment: you are correct that is a typo. ill fix the code above